# How can i match the values of a column according to another of a data frame in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two datasets that look like this:
The first is :

| id | gear |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | A |
| A2 | B |
| A3 | C |
| A4 | D |
| A5 | E |
| A6 | F |
| A7 | G |
| A8 | H |
| A9 | I |
| A10 | G |

And the second :

| id | gear2 |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | A |
| A4 | E |
| A2 | A |
| A5 | E |
| A13 | B |
| A3 | C |
| A9 | I |
| A8 | B |
| A7 | G |
| A20 | G |
| A21 | B |
| A23 | D |
| A33 | E |

There two unbalanced data frames.The first data frame is the recorded data set.The second one contains what is known about the gear coming from an id.I want to check the first data frame if what is recorded actually is known or unknown.Specifically i want to check given the id code to check is the gear is the same in both data frames.But individually on each id. Ideally the result must be :

| id | gear | CHECK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A | TRUE |
| A2 | B | FALSE |
| A3 | C | TRUE |
| A4 | D | FALSE |
| A5 | E | TRUE |
| A6 | F | N/A |
| A7 | G | TRUE |
| A8 | H | FALSE |
| A9 | I | TRUE |
| A10 | G | N/A |

```
id1 = c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10")
Gear1 = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","G")
dat1 = tibble(id1,Gear1);dat1

id2 = c("A1","A4","A2","A5","A13","A3","A9","A8","A7","A20","A21","A23","A33")
Gear2 = c("A","E","A","E","B","C","I","B","G","G","B","D","E")
dat2 = tibble(id2,Gear2);dat2
```

How can i do it in R using the dplyr package ?
Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `left_join` and then compare the two columns:

```
library(dplyr)

dat1 %>% 
  left_join(dat2, by = c("id1" = "id2")) %>% 
  mutate(CHECK = Gear1 == Gear2) %>% 
  select(id = id1, gear = Gear1, CHECK)

# A tibble: 10 × 3
   id    gear  CHECK
   <chr> <chr> <lgl>
 1 A1    A     TRUE 
 2 A2    B     FALSE
 3 A3    C     TRUE 
 4 A4    D     FALSE
 5 A5    E     TRUE 
 6 A6    F     NA   
 7 A7    G     TRUE 
 8 A8    H     FALSE
 9 A9    I     TRUE 
10 A10   G     NA
```

Have a look at the [`dplyr` documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/two-table.html) how to use joins.

### Edit

Thanks to [Ritchie Sacramento](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835261/ritchie-sacramento) for the trick to do the renaming directly in the `select` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dat1 |> 
  mutate(check = ifelse(!id1 %in% dat2$id2, 
                        NA,
                        ifelse(paste(id1, Gear1) %in% paste(dat2$id2, dat2$Gear2), 
                               TRUE, 
                               FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat1 = rename(dat1, id = 'id1')
dat2 = rename(dat2, id = 'id2')

check_data = dat1 %>% 
  full_join(dat2, by='id') %>% 
  mutate(check = ifelse(Gear1==Gear2, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  filter(! is.na(Gear1))
```

Output:

```
check_data
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   id    Gear1 Gear2 check
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>
 1 A1    A     A     TRUE 
 2 A2    B     A     FALSE
 3 A3    C     C     TRUE 
 4 A4    D     E     FALSE
 5 A5    E     E     TRUE 
 6 A6    F     NA    NA   
 7 A7    G     G     TRUE 
 8 A8    H     B     FALSE
 9 A9    I     I     TRUE 
10 A10   G     NA    NA
```